# Google Analytics Code Insert for WordPress Twenty Twenty Two Theme

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I was using Google Analytics by inserting the code in header file of the theme. Recently I have switched the theme to twenty twenty two which is an entirely different when it comes to customization. When I go to header file, there is no <head> tag in the file rather the code is available in <div>

I have inserted the code in <div> but it does not work. I added the <head> tag but it isn't working.

Comment: Why would you edit the tracking into your theme rather than [use a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/google+analytics/) that can insert it for you?

Comment: Yes, I have used Monsterinsights but the thing is it take a lot of space. Furthermore, it only gives one metric of Google Analytics whereas if we insert the code, it takes no space and provide almost all of the metrics and can be used very effectively.

Comment: There are also plugins that allow you to insert your own code in the `<head>` https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/insert+head/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the code to the header.php file for the Twenty Twenty Two theme, specifically between the <head ***> and  elements.

If you want to be sure you have them in the correct place you can use the https://tagassistant.google.com service.

Another way to check that you have the code in the right place is to use the [Site Kit plugin by Google](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-site-kit/) to insert your Google Analytics code. After doing so you can check the placement by reviewing your sites source code. You can then remove the Site Kit plugin and manually insert in the same position.

Comment: You are a gem. @James Osborne